# Unable to export GeoTIFF file with different datatypes per different bands

Tags: gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt

Already read [Merge Multi-Band Geotiff with different datatypes (with gdal)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207030/merge-multi-band-geotiff-with-different-datatypes-with-gdal) but can't apply that solution so please do not flag as duplicate.

I have near 3.000 geotiff files that I need to merge into just one.

this is what I done so far:

`gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list list_of_files.txt -overwrite -addalpha images.vrt`

and then

`gdal_translate -tr 0.000170 0.000170 -r cubicspline -of GTiff images.vrt test.tif`

I've got this warning:

`Warning 1: Unable to export GeoTIFF file with different datatypes per
different bands. All bands should have the same types in TIFF.`

I can get rid of the warning when remove `-addalpha` from `gdalbuildvrt`.

I'm a complete newbie on this so I ask: What is the implication of the `-addalpha` parameter and that warning if I choose to keep it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html):

> **-addalpha**: Adds an alpha mask band to the VRT [...] The alpha band is filled on-the-fly with the value 0 in areas without any source raster, and with value 255 in areas with source raster

The alpha channel is added as a Band of type byte, while the rest of your files are probably a different Type (e.g. UINT16). Like that you cannot combine them in one GeoTiff.

Best option would be to create a **[mask](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)** from the alpha channel.

When you have an RGB image:

```
gdal_translate -tr 0.000170 0.000170 -r cubicspline -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask 4 -of GTiff images.vrt test.tif
```

When you have a Single-band image:

```
gdal_translate -tr 0.000170 0.000170 -r cubicspline -b 1 -mask 2 -of GTiff images.vrt test.tif
```

If you don't know the band numbers, find out after creating the VRT with this command:

```
gdalinfo images.vrt
```